# Find the three closest surrounding neighbors from a data

Tags: geometry, searching

I have a data of coordinates $x$ and $y$ where we know the range of both variables, e.g. $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$. So for a given any random point $\theta_0=(x_0~~y_0)^T$ in the range of $x$ and $y$ I would like to find the closest 3 points to $\theta_0$ from my data that form a triangle where $\theta_0$ is included in that triangle (could be either on the edge or the center). So what are the coordinates of those three points from my data.

Comment: What is your definition of "closest 3 points" in your data? Does that mean that the minimum distance among the 3 distances to your point is minimum, or the maximum distance among the 3 distances to your point is minimum, or the sum of the 3 distances is minimum? Or something else?

Comment: The closest 3 points in terms of the euclidean distance to avoid the case where you find a bigger triangle.

Comment: I don’t think your question has a well-defined answer. For example, which three points do you want in this picture, where the red point is your “random point”? http://i.imgur.com/NvZNAMp.png

Comment: @SteveKass you are right but those coordinates $(x,y)$ yield a surface with the third coordinate that I already have $f(x,y)$. So more specifically it should be the triangle from that $f(x,y)$ surface..

Comment: I don’t see what your comment about a surface has to do with anything. You’ve still got to define what you’re looking for, and “closest three points in terms of euclidean distance that form a triangle including $\theta_0$” doesn’t unambiguously define three specific points. The question @user2566092 asked is still unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I think one should compute all the euclidean distances between $\theta_0$ and all the other points from the data then sort them. The first 3 points that don't form a straight line is the triangle that we are looking for. We can first find the slopes of the segments joining any two pairs of the 3 points. If they are different then it's a triangle. The last thing to do is to check also whether $\theta_0$ lies inside the triangle defined by the 3 points.